# Ionic 4 hardware backbutton close on double tap not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working on my application but stuck in one problem which is hardware backbutton. I need when user click on backbutton so it will not back the app or close just show some toast.

And on double tap close the app. But its not working no toast is showing and hardware back button is working .

This is my code in app.component.ts

```
  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
              // this does work
        this.routerOutlets.forEach((outlet: IonRouterOutlet) => {
          if (outlet && outlet.canGoBack()) {
              outlet.pop();

          } else if (this.router.url === '/wallet') {
              if (new Date().getTime() - this.lastTimeBackPress < this.timePeriodToExit) {
                  // this.platform.exitApp(); // Exit from app
                  navigator['app'].exitApp(); // work for ionic 4

              } else {
                this.toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                  message: 'double tap to exit.',
                  duration: 2000,
                  position: 'bottom'
                }).then((toastData)=>{
                  console.log(toastData);
                  toastData.present();
                });

              this.lastTimeBackPress = new Date().getTime();
              }
          }
      });

    });
  }
```

Its working fine in some ionic version but my version is ionic 6.0.1

I have try with dfferent answers this is working but how can i enable double tap close int it ? now its not closing or back on hardware button but i need to clsoe app on double tap

```
  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
              // this does work
      this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(9999, () => {
        document.addEventListener('backbutton', function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
          console.log('hello');
        }, false);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Did you try using `platform.backButton.subscribe()`?

Comment: @Mridul updated my question. yes its working but dont know how can i enable double tap close app in this code.

Comment: I have added some code reference I guess it may work for you check it.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this code and make changes if required as per your requirement.

Under `initializeApp()` call a function `backbuttonSubscribeMethod()`

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.backbuttonSubscribeMethod();
    });
  }
```

Define your method

```
backbuttonSubscribeMethod() {
    let a = 0;
    this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
        a++;
        if (a == 2) { // logic for double tap
          navigator['app'].exitApp();
        }
    });
  }
```

Unsubscribe it under this

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.platform.backButton.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: try this its notworking. On back click its going back.

Comment: On which page do you want to perform this? add it's path

Comment: Or it has to be for all the pages?

Comment: i add the path but not working. can you tell how its work in all pagesso i try with this also

Comment: If you have defined this in `app.module` it will work for all pages

Comment: it is working for me ionic v6.12.2 but one difference, I have defined this in app.component.ts....And don't remember implements OnDestroy...Thx...

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me. within `initializeApp()` add below snipet

```
this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
    if (Date.now() - this.lastBack < 500) { // logic for double tap: delay of 500ms between two clicks of back button
      navigator['app'].exitApp();
    }
    this.lastBack= Date.now();
});
```

Define   `private lastBack = Date.now();` as a variable in your Component